# Extract data from an urarranged file

Tags: excel

I want to format my excel data.

data format which i have is like this:

[image: is like this]

where i would like to format this data in this format:

[image: in this format]

Is there any automate way?

Comment: There is an automated way, but you'll have to write it out in VBA and it will be very specific to your input and output :/

Comment: a little bit guidance will be very helpful.

Comment: If you were to do this manually, exactly how would you do it?  Think about the exact steps and reduce each one to VBA (maybe starting with pseudocode). If there's something *specific* you need help with, then post a question about that specific step, along with the code you tried.